# Solr search across child and parent documents, return scored individual results

Tags: solr

Over simplified example of data, but say I have parent documents that are posts. These post documents have 2 types of child documents, one that details visibility and another that stores comments on the posts. I want to be able to search for
"alfalfa" and only return the posts and comments that I can see that match.

However I want to be able to return the individual comments as results and have them be able to be scored and sorted against the posts as well.

```
      {
        "id":"post123",
        "content": "Alfalfa is great",
        "_childDocuments_":[
        {
          "id":"comment123",
          "message": "sure is!"
        },
        {
          "id": "comment1234",
          "message": "eh alfalfa is ok"
        },
        {
          "id": "canview123"
          "user_id": "user123"
        }]}
        {
          "id":"post456",
          "content":"what is the best vegetable",
          "user_id": "user123",
          "_childDocuments_":[
        {
          "id":"comment456",
          "message": "alfalfa is the best"
        },
        {
          "id": "canview456",
          "org_id": "org456",
        },
        ]
       }
```

So in this example, I'd like to be able to perform a search "alfalfa" and if I'm "user123" and have access to "org456", I would like to see results and be able to search score them.

"id":"post123"
"id:"comment1234"
"id:"comment456"

I know with [child doc transformation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html#TransformingResultDocuments-_child_-ChildDocTransformerFactory) you can filter and surface the child docs that might match. And supposedly you can do a bit more with subquery, though I am having trouble figuring out the right syntax to do so.

So I am asking, is this possible given the current way the data is structured, if so how might I go about doing it. If not are there suggestions for other ways to achieve this? If we don't nest the comments then we'd have to add visibility child documents on each of the comments which can become expensive to reindex when those visibility rules change.